# Regex handle substring different

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to check the syntax of a pseudo-function-call:

```
(\$[^\W]+\$)
```

So if I have a path or something else I can check if the syntax of a containing function-call is valid.

A function-call always starts and ends with the $-char.

To verify the syntax of a path I have the following regex which matches the full path:

```
^([A-Za-z]\:|\\|\.)(\\[^\\\/:*?""<>|]*)+[\\]$
```

I've tried to combine this two regular expression with **|** but then every functioncall which matches the path-syntax is valid.

I need a regex that checks the path-syntax and if there is a function call (leading and ending $) the function-call-syntax should be checked for that.

**Valid strings**

- C:\temp\testfolder\
- C:\$getTempPath$\testfolder\
- C:\$getTempPath$\$getTestFolder$\
- C:\programms (x86)\$getAppFolder$\
- C:\temp\alternative$ folder name (for users)\

**Invalid strings**

- C:\$getPrograms(x86)$\testfolder\
- C:\$my function$\test\

Comment: If your path can contain directory names or function calls, and the directory names never contain a dollar sign, just put the function regex inside the path regex as one alternative for path names (and make sure you exclude dollar sign from the characters which are valid in path names, but that already seems to be the case).  If indeed this is what you are looking for, please [edit] your question to better explain your requirements.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/DThW9R/1

Comment: $ is valid for folders. function-calls have to be between two $ signs. A single appearing $ should be interpreted as part of the path

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: this is nearly what I was looking for. The only problem is that a single $ is also valid for a path in windows. something like 'C:\hiddenprograms$\allfiles\' is valid in windows.

Comment: Why is ``C:\$getPrograms(x86)$\testfolder\`` invalid then? It seems your question lacks precise requirements.

Comment: because the `getPrograms(x86)` is between to `$` chars. so it's a function-call. And in a functioncall **(** and **)** is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*\\\$\w*[^\w\\][^\\]*\$(?:\\|$))(?:[A-Za-z]:|[\\.])(?:\\[^\\\/:*?"<>|]*)+\\$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DThW9R/3)

The main idea is to fail any string that contains a subpath that starts with `$`, then contains any non-word char other than `\` (a  dir separator, this might require adjustment), and then has any amount of chars other than `\` up to a `$` and `\` or end of string.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\\\$\w*[^\w\\][^\\]*\$(?:\\|$))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the pattern is matched immediately to the right from the start of the string:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\\\$` - a `\$` subtring
  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars
  - `[^\w\\]` - any char but a word and `\` chars
  - `[^\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `\` char
  - `\$` - a `$` char
  - `(?:\\|$)` - either `\` or end of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z]:|[\\.])` - either an ASCII letter and a `:` after it, or `\` or `.`
- `(?:\\[^\\\/:*?"<>|]*)+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `\\` - a `\` char
  - `[^\\\/:*?"<>|]*` - 0+ chars other than those defined in the character class
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

The regex provided by Wiktor Stribiżew may work if tweaked a little:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]:|[\\.])(?:\\(?:\$\w+\$|(?!\$[^\\\/:*?"<>|]+\$\\)[^\\\/:*?"<>|]+))+\\$
```

The changes are:

1. allow $ characters in path names
2. add a negative look-ahead expression to prevent it from allowing $ characters to surround path names