# Match substring and escape special characters

Tags: regex, xsd

I have the following regular expression to verify the syntax of a so called macro-call:

```
(\b\$[A-Za-z:]*\$\b)
```

And I have the following regular expression to match a folderpath:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]{1}:\\|[\\]{2}|[A-Za-z])(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|]*)+\\$
```

Now I have two requirements to achieve:

1. I need to check if the following collection of special characters only appear masked: `= " ' / # , $` The mask is the #-char. So `=` is only allowed if it appears as `#=`.
2. I want to join the two regular expressions from above. So that I have the regular expression for a path where every special character is masked with the `#` sign. And I want to check the macro-syntax if a macro appears.

A macro is always between not masked `$` chars.

**Valid Examples:**

> C:\temp\test\
>
> \\fileserver\production#$\users\
>
> D:\$FindDirectory$\approot\
>
> C:\$FindDirectory$\pathwith#$dollar\
>
> C:\$findroot:appuser$\Test with equal#=123 and hashtag ##\
>
> **Invalid Examples:** (-> with reason)
>
> C:\temp\test `-> no ending \`
>
> \\fileserver\production$\users\ `-> not masked $`
>
> C:\$FindDirectory1$\approot\ `-> invalid char (1) in macro-call`

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with regular expressions...

---

Context:

In my application I have an editor where the user can provide xml-based input. In this input he can define so called macros which he may use afterwards.

So a scenario can be:

1. He defines a macro to get a certain folder path and names it 'getAppFolder'
2. He wants to define a path for a copy-action where he wants to use his previously defined macro (e.g. C:\programs\$getAppFolder$\appdir)
3. That data is pushed into a custom output-format where the above mentioned special characters must be escaped so that another application (which is not written by me) can interpret that input data

**Just got another case, which I just forgot**

A macro-call can also be at the beginning of the string like:

$getFolderPath:root$\appdir\

---

I've modified the solution provided by coladict to the following:

`^(?:(?:(\$[A-Za-z0-9:.]*\$)|(?:#[="'#,\$]|[^#$])*))+$`

The only thing that is missing is that invalid path-characters like \ / : * ? " < > not recognised and something like `C:\temp\hello<world` is a match (but it shouldn't match)

Comment: In what environment / language?

Comment: This looks eerily similar to your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693143/regex-handle-substring-different

Comment: That doesn't mean they both lead into one answer. @tripleee

Comment: I use it in a xsd-schema-file which is used in my c#-application

Comment: No, just pointing out for context. Perhaps the OP should provide even more context, though... Like why use regex for this (especially if you're not familiar with it), and why do they have to parse this funky ad-hoc format in the first place, instead of using something well-defined and standard?

Comment: XSD regex is very specific. It does not support any zero width assertions, so you cannot use `^`, `$` or `\b`. The pattern always must match the whole string.

Comment: `\b\$` and `\$\b` are a bad idea : `\b` marks the boundary of a word, that is the delimitation between a word character (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`) and a non-word character (the complement of the previous class). Since `$` are non-word characters, it means you expect your `$something$` to be enclosed in word characters (which it isn't when you consider "\$getAppFolder$\")

Comment: Yes, just realized that this is a bad idea. Because it's also possible that the path is just a macro-call like $emitPath:userpath:write$

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make a regex that matches all your given examples and rejects the invalid ones, but you might disagree with it.

Tested on [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html).

```
in plain text: ^(?:[A-Za-z]:\\|\\{2})(?:(?:(\$[A-Za-z:]*\$)|[^\$](?:#[="'/#,\$]|[^#$])*[^\$]))+\\$
in C# string: "^(?:[A-Za-z]:\\\\|\\\\{2})(?:(?:(\\$[A-Za-z:]*\\$)|[^\\$](?:#[=\"'/#,\\$]|[^#$])*[^\\$]))+\\\\$"
```

From this part you gave, trying to match the drive, I believe the last segment is invalid and removed it:

```
(?:[A-Za-z]{1}:\\|[\\]{2}|[A-Za-z])
```

Now this part is:

```
(?:[A-Za-z]:\\|\\{2})
```

The rest is pretty interesting, but the idea of how to do the escaping with `#` with the regex `(?:#[="'/#,\$]|.)+` is literally the same way as the example C string parser, which I can't remember where I found.

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for. The only thing that does not work like expected is the masking of the so called special characters. A input-string like: `c:\temp\$getAppTemp:userscope$\sub#directory\` In this case the # in sub#directory should be ## to be valid

Comment: @Tomtom done. Though I have no idea what was different now that I put in the same data and stuff, and one of the checks failed, and I had to fix it.

Comment: c:\temp\$getAppTemp:userscope$\sub#directory\ stil doesn't work